# What does it mean to "drink a lot of haterade"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, slang

A friend recently posted on their Facebook status that she has "apparently been drinking lots of haterade lately"[sic]. Does this mean other people are annoyed with her or she's annoyed with other people? What does this phrase mean?

Comment: I think this about sums it up: [Haterade Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Haterade/30930202414?sk=info)

Comment: @jcolebrand Sorry! I thought you just mixed up some words. Next time I'll ask.

Comment: no no, it's fine, I figured that was likely the case. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The term is a take-off on an American beverage called "gatorade," which is what we would now call a "power drink." She is drinking "haterade," appears to not mean that she is not only ingesting "hate," but in a heavy dose, like the beverage.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the OPs question...which direction is the hate directed, towards the drinker or towards others? 'Drinking ots' could mean that she is the object of hatred of others -or- that she is getting a lot of resources to help her express her hatred of others.

Comment: "She is drinking haterade" means she is doing the hating.

Comment: There has to be some influence from the phrase ["drinking the Kool-Aid"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid) here.

Comment: I'm with Mitch, what's the directionality? How do you determine she is the one doing the hating?

Comment: @jcolebrand - Because the pun isn't on _hate_, it's on _hater_ (as in "[haters gonna hate](http://www.hatersgoingtohate.com/)"). A person who _drinks haterade_ becomes a _hater_.

Comment: Also, that facebook page someone linked to in the comments on the OP defines haterade as "a metaphorical drink that haters sip on", which seems pretty apt to me.

Comment: @jcolebrand: You have to consider its origin in the root phrase ["drinking the Kool-Aid"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid). With that phrase, the one drinking the Kool-Aid is the one behaving strangely. Here, she is "drinking the haterade", which would imply that she is behaving strangely, so she is the one doing the hating.